# Source folders for a maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I have a that uses maven... and I want to put it in my working environment with eclipse(Galileo)... the project is in a svn server, and I can create check out the project and everything looks OK. I even can run the unit test and everything is working there.
However, now that everything is there I wanted to work in the code, and oh surprise there are no packages in my project... I mean all the source code is in the src folder and browsing through it i can see all my files, ut if I open the files from there, the files are opened as text files with no coloring, but worst no help at all about errors in compilation.

I don't know what im I doing wrong now, because I had the same project in other machine and it was working well.

So here is what I did, please let me know if you notice if I did something wrong, miss any steps or anything that can help me:

1. In the SVN Repository (Using subclipse 1.6.10) I added my SVN Repository
2. Browsed to the folder where I have the pom file
3. Right Click> Check out as a Maven project...(Using m2eclipse 0.10.020100209)
4. Used the default options and finish.
5. The projects were created with no problem. I said projects because this maven project has modules, and each module became a project in eclipse.
6. Back in the java perspective, Right click in the project, Run as > maven test(Using JWebUnitTest, because I am testing  a servlet)
7. BUILD SUCCESS!!

But as I said there is not packages so I can't really develop in this environment.

Any help??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, however I noticed that eclipse itself was behaving weird when I try to create a package there and I didn't have the option.
So I found out that for some reason that eclipse installation wasn't giving me any of the Java basic options.
So I download a new eclipse installation.. and I repeat the whole process and now is working...
No clue what was the problem with this eclipse because I was using it for other projects and I don't know when I lost the basic functionalities!

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Eclipse is like Windows xp, you have to fresh-install it every once in a while

Answer (score 1):

When performing a svn checkout as maven project, m2eclipse writes what it does in a console window, accessible using the "console" panel, where there is a drop-down list of all available consoles. What does this console tells ?

Besides, if you can perform a maven test, you can also, in the maven menu (of your contextual menu) do a "update project configuration" which *should* do the same thing and configure eclipse for your project.

As a last test, is there a maven icon over your project ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested your setup on command line with Maven ? Does a mvn package work without errors ? The location for the sources in Maven is src/main/java + Package name. Have you opened the project as a Maven project?

Comment: Yes it works from a command line... and no errors!
The source path in maven is indeed src/main/java.
What do you mean open the project as Maven project? if is checked out as Maven  project I assume avery time is been opened as a Maven Project

Comment: Yeah if you checked it out as Maven it's ok..may be oversight that.